# Is there a way to skip the first value using itertuples?

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python. I am trying to get the sum of all the value beside the first two value. But I do not know how to remove the first value when using itertuples.

I know i can drop the columns but I would prefer not.

```
Year Population Positive affect Negative affect
2017   10000         5               0
2017   15000         10             15
```

the output will be

```
10005
15025
```

Comment: `df[1:].itertuples()` but a better answer is: Don't use `itertuples`.

Comment: @coldspeed That would omit the first row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, there is no need for iteration at all. Instead, use the vectorised method `sum` along with the accessor `iloc`:

```
df.iloc[:, 1:].sum(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
0    10005
1    15025
```